# transform a mouse event (drag) to a touch screen event

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to transform my mouse event to a swipe event (for touch screen), but after hours and hours, I can't figure out how to do it.

Here's my code :

```
public function DraggedItem(stageRef:Stage, grabbedItem:Object){

            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            toolbar = Engine.toolbar;
            usableItems = Engine.usableItems;
            inv = Engine.inv;
            puzzle = Engine.puzzle;
            player = Engine.player;
            linesData = Engine.linesData;

            inv.draggingItem = true;
            Mouse.hide();

            itemRef = getDefinitionByName(grabbedItem.displayName.toLowerCase()+"Proper");
            draggedItem = new itemRef;
            stageRef.addChild(draggedItem);
            draggedItem.displayName = grabbedItem.displayName;
            if (grabbedItem.lookTag)
                draggedItem.lookTag = grabbedItem.lookTag;
            draggedItem.x = mouseX + x;
            draggedItem.y = mouseY + y;
            draggedItem.scaleX = itemScale;
            draggedItem.scaleY = itemScale;
            stageRef.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragItem, false, 0, true);
            stageRef.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, itemHitTest, false, 0, true);
            draggedItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemClick, false, 0, true);

        }

        private function dragItem(e:MouseEvent):void{
            draggedItem.x = mouseX + x;
            draggedItem.y = mouseY + y;
        }
```

On my computer, when I click on my inventory and the select a item, I can drag it where I want on the screen (the item become the mouse, and the mouse is hide).

So I'm trying to transform it for touch screen. 
I've tried to using "event.stageX" instead of "mouseX", but it didn't work. 
I've tried to replace mouseEvent by TransformGestureEvent, but it didn't work.

And When I click on my item in the inventory, the item stay stuck in the middle corner of the screen and I can't move it. (it's happening just when I'm exporting with adobe Air for Android, if I'm exporting in swf it's working just fine).

Do you know how I can do it ?

Here's a video of the problem : uploaded.net/file/lkwqsgm7

Thank you very much !

Comment: why not using TouchEvent?

Comment: your not instantiating your dragged item properly, needs brackets  `new itemRef()`

Comment: you don't show your `itemHitTest` method.

Comment: MouseEvents work fine on a touch screen. Are you wanting multitouch? (so you can drag multiple items at the same time?)

Comment: I supposed it was the problem but I don't really. Here is my problem : When I click on my item in the inventory, the item stay stuck in the middle corner of the screen and I can't move it. (it's happening just when I'm exporting with adobe Air for Android, if I'm exporting in swf it's working just fine). Here's a video of the problem : uploaded.net/file/lkwqsgm7

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the built in gestures of flash.

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE; //you need to enable gestures

stageRef.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe); 
function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    if (e.offsetX == 1) { 
        //swiped right
        draggedItem.x += someValue;
    }else{
        //swiped left
        draggedItem.x -= someValue;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, the swipe event is only for general swiping, if you're actually just dragging an object from position A to position B, this is not a swipe, but well...a drag.  I'm not clear on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

If you do want to do multitouch, just change your `MouseEvents` to `TouchEvents`.  Mouse_Down is equivalent to TOUCH_BEGIN  and mouse up is equivalent to TOUCH_END.

Comment: I supposed it was the problem but I don't really. Here is my problem : When I click on my item in the inventory, the item stay stuck in the middle corner of the screen and I can't move it. (it's happening just when I'm exporting with adobe Air for Android, if I'm exporting in swf it's working just fine). Here's a video of the problem : http://uploaded.net/file/lkwqsgm7